# Create multiple matrices in one for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, dataframe

I am new to R and currently learning to create for loops.

What I want to do is create 6 matrices that have a similar structure like this (only difference is that row "a" varies with the number of the matrix):

```
matrix1<- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5, dimnames= list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

for(i in 1:5){
matrix1[1,]= 1
matrix1[2,]= round(rpois(5,1), digits=0)
matrix1[3,]= round(rpois(5,1), digits= 0)
matrix1[4,]= round(rnorm(5, 50, 25), digits= 0)
matrix1[5,]= round(rnorm(5, 50, 25), digits= 0)
}
```

is there any efficient way using for loops instead of doing this individually?

I also considered creating 6 5*5Matrices filled with NA values and then filling these with the desired values afterwards but I do not know how to do it.

It would be very nice if you could help me out!
Thanks!

Comment: Write a function of `x` to make the matrix, then do `lapply(values_for_x, fun)`? Note that it's better to have a list of matrices than embed matrix numbers in names like `matrix1`, `matrix2`, ...

Comment: but how do I write this function? could you give me an example?

Comment: `fun <- function(x){ your_code_here_over_multiple_lines }` Inside the curly braces, you can write your code as above, making sure that it uses the function argument (`x` or whatever you want to call it) to make the "a" row differ as you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is not needed and your code runs without it. In R, the for loop allows you a temporary object that iterates (in your case) from 1 to 5 by 1 each loop. In order to take advantage of the looping, you need to use the `i`. Your current for loop actually just overwrites itself 5 times.

Here is a loop that creates 6 matrices in a list. The trick here is that I use `i` not only to create a new element (a matrix) in the list, but also to set the first row to vary with the number matrix that it is.

```
# First it is good to initialize an object that you will iterate over
lists <- vector("list", 6) # initialize to save time

for(i in 1:6){
  # create a new matrix and set all values in it to be i
  lists[[i]] <- matrix(i, nrow = 5, ncol = 5, dimnames= list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
))
  # change the remaining rows
  lists[[i]]["b",] <- round(rpois(5,1), digits = 0)
  lists[[i]]["c",] <- round(rpois(5,1), digits = 0)
  lists[[i]]["d",] <- round(rnorm(5, 50, 25), digits= 0)
  lists[[i]]["e",] <- round(rnorm(5, 50, 25), digits= 0)
}

# Properly name your lists
names(lists) <- paste0("Matrix",1:6)

# Now you can call the lists individually with
lists$Matrix1

# Or send them all to your environment with
list2env(lists, env = .GlobalEnv)
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have any more questions~